# Read recovered Stickies

Tags: macos, catalina, stickies

Fortunately I was able to recover lost Stickies after Catalina update in \Library\StickiesDatabase. However, the text file is encoded in such a way that I can't read it. I can hardly recognize some words. How can I translate this into a readable text please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The Catalina update just removed the dashboard. For me, all the notes were available and opened automatically upon launching the Stickies app. What happens when you launch that app?

Comment: When I open the app I get a blank sticky note, that's what I meant by "lost Stickies". thanks